# Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element or Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-router, react-router-dom

I keep getting the error:

> Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element or
> Component. This means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a null value
> by default resulting in an "empty" page.

when attempting to route to different screens.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import Register from "./pages/Register"
import Login from "./pages/login"
import Write from "./pages/Write"
import Home from "./pages/home"
import Single from "./pages/single"
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import "./project.scss"

import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom";

const main = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    Element: <main />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        Element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/post/:id",
        element: <Single />,
      },
      {
        path: "/write",
        element: <Write />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    element: <Register />,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },

])

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='container'>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried multiple solutions that I have found but none of them have worked yet. I understand that the `react-router@6` `Route` component uses an `element` prop taking a `ReactNode` (e.g. JSX) or `Component` prop taking a React Element, but I am not sure how to fit it to my code.

Answer (score 1):

The [`RouteObject`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration) type has an `element` prop, not `Element`.

> ```
> interface RouteObject {
>   path?: string;
>   index?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   id?: string;
>   loader?: LoaderFunction;
>   action?: ActionFunction;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;       // <-- element
>   Component?: React.ComponentType | null;
>   errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   ErrorBoundary?: React.ComponentType | null;
>   handle?: RouteObject["handle"];
>   shouldRevalidate?: ShouldRevalidateFunction;
>   lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<RouteObject>;
> }
> ```

In Javascript, identifiers are case-sensitive. Change the `Element` properties to `element`.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Main />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/post/:id",
        element: <Single />,
      },
      {
        path: "/write",
        element: <Write />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    element: <Register />,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
]);
```

Comment: I used your method, the error did disappear, but the web page still remain blank

Comment: @YunkaiWang Is your `Main` component rendering an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their `element` content, specifically so `Home` can be rendered on path `"/"`? See [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for details.

Comment: still don't get it, the browser did not give me any error message.  The Home component will be rendered inside the <Outlet /> of the Main component when the path is /. This structure allows for nesting routes within the Main layout while rendering their respective components in the designated areas of the UI.

Comment: @YunkaiWang It won't give any error message because there's no error, `Main` just needs to render an `Outlet` so its nested children routes can also be rendered. You are trying to render `Home` via the `"/"` path in the address bar, right?

Comment: yes, i am trying to render Home via the "/"

Comment: @YunkaiWang So you can see the `Main` layout route component *and* the `Home` component when the path is `"/"`?